# Should I downvote partial answer?

Tags: support, down-votes

If I encounter a partial/incomplete answer (not partially wrong), should I downvote it?

Comment: That's up to you. Definitely leave a comment and explain what you think is wrong so that the author can correct/improve his/her answer.

Comment: @Felix any predefined rules here,because I do not want to demotivate a person's 50% correct efforts.rather I would leave a comment.what do u say

Comment: No, there are no rules, the tooltip only gives a hint by saying "this answer is not useful". Do you think the answer is not useful? For example, I hardly downvote but leave a comment instead. I downvote after some time if the author did not correct his/her answer (based on mine or other peoples comments) or if the answer was completely wrong.

Comment: I would suggest - that if the person acknowledged that his/her answer is a partial one, then no downvote is needed.  However if the person answering has totally disregarded part of the OP's question then a downvote is in order.  In both cases, comments cant hurt :)

Comment: @Felix I feel there should be rule. anyways tx.

Comment: OTOH, if someone's foolish enough to ask multiple questions in the same “Question”, please downvote the asker (leaving a comment as to why).

Comment: Partial answer != Partially incorrect answer. Which one do you mean?

Comment: @Pekka I mean partial answer not partial incorrect answer

Comment: related: [Placeholder Answers: Will update with answer soon!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269993/839601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if I read an answer which is 50% right or around 50% right,should I downvote that answer?

I don't, depends I guess. Personally I'd leave a comment mentioning the wrong part & if the post is edited to correct the mistake I'd add in the +1.

Of course, you have have the liberty to edit out & correct it on your own, if you're so confident.

Answer (score 12):

> I mean partial answer not partial incorrect answer

In general, partial answers are fine *if what they already contain is truly helpful.* It's absolutely not fair to downvote a contribution that may help the OP at least *some* of the way. Sometimes, answers are also intentionally incomplete if the OP is asking a "plz send teh codez" or a "fix my wall of code" type question.

Only if the partial answer was given in bad faith (i.e. it is incomplete and doesn't help the OP at all;maybe it was just too lazy to address the *hard* part) downvoting *might* be appropriate IMO.

Comment: +1 Sometimes an (intentionally) incomplete answer helps asker 100% though, simply because the answerer understood the question more than the author him/herself.

Answer (score 1):

### It's up to you.

Consider this image:

[image]

<sup>Image credits to *Shog9 ♦*</sup>

If you think the partial answer is fine, leave it as-is or vote it up. Otherwise if you don't think it's enough or even partially wrong, you can vote it down.